# TableView data pass to other tableView AND navigation controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Firstly, I tried all segue codes but not true result...

(*iOS 7*) My storyboard starts with Tab Bar and has a Button to Model -> Table View with Navigation Controller. That TableView has JSON datas. If click a cell you pass to another tableViewController with push segue.
My push codes:

```
KatAltViewController * ilet = [[KatAltViewController alloc] init];
    Kategoriler * currentKategoriler = [kategorilerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    ilet.cid = currentKategoriler.cid;
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:ilet animated:YES];
```

First tableView has not problem but if you click a cell to second table view, console gives that error:

```
2013-12-23 17:08:59.871 project02[3903:70b] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2013-12-23 17:09:00.238 project02[3903:70b] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
```

So, i click Back button in second tableview: screen is black!

```
2013-12-23 17:10:34.081 project02[3903:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'
```

how I fix that?

Comment: Do you still have segues attached to a button or table view cell? You shouldn't be using alloc init to get an instance of KatAltViewController, if it's one of the scenes in your storyboard. You should use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: or use a segue.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have `NavigationController` in your storyboard and if you use this code

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ilet animated:YES];
```

you call 2 times to `NavigationController`.

So can you try this code part?

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    passElement=[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f target:self selector:@selector(passToOtherTableView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];


}
-(void)passToOtherTableView{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"passSegue" sender:self];

}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"passSegue"]){
        SecondTableViewController *controller = (SecondTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.value = passElement;
    }
}
```

I hope this can be help for you.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all answers.
Yes @TwentyThr23, i called two times NavigationController...

I deleted these codes, because I already push cells on storyboard;

```
KatAltViewController * ilet = [[KatAltViewController alloc] init];
Kategoriler * currentKategoriler = [kategorilerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
ilet.cid = currentKategoriler.cid;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ilet animated:YES];
```

and I added these lines;

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"altKategoriS"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    KatAltViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    Kategoriler * currentKategoriler = [kategorilerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    destViewController.cid = currentKategoriler.cid;
  }
}
```